# how to generate keypair from secret phrase (mnemonic) SOLANA

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, blockchain, solana

I am working with Solana and phantom wallet I have a wallet with a public key and I have it's secret phrase composed of 12 words.
when I generate keypairs from the secret phrase I use:

```
const getKeyPair = (mnemomic) => {
  const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemomic).slice(0, 32);
  const Keypair = web3.Keypair.fromSeed(seed);
  return Keypair;
};
```

the generated keypair has publicKey and privateKey , but when am checking my balance using the generated public key I find the balance is always 0 even when I try to airdrop Sol using my code it's not getting in the account.

But if I check using my public key from phantom wallet I get the Sol I have and if I want to airdrop sols they also proceed normally.

Why is my generated public key not the same as the one in phantom wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to generate the **publicKey** and **privateKey** from the **seed phrase**  using this command :

> solana-keygen recover 'prompt:?key=0/0' -o phantom_wallet.json
>
> remark : our account may have many wallets the command above access
> the first wallet , if we need to access wallet number 10 for example
> we need to change the **'prompt:?key=0/0'** to **'prompt:?key=10/0'**
> "only the first 0 is changing"

next this will generate public key "will be written in the console" and a  json file with secret key contains an array of **64 element** which is **the secret key**.
**now to generate the KEYPAIRS in solana web3 javascript SDK**
we do the following:

```
 let seed = Uint8Array.from(
    process.env.REACT_APP_OUR_SECRET_KEY.split(",")
  ).slice(0, 32);

  // create keypairs
  let KEYPAIRS = web3.Keypair.fromSeed(seed);
```

> IMPORTANT : in .env files REACT_APP_OUR_SECRET_KEY is stored without brackets [
> ]
> example : 15,320,52,...
> as we see a table without brackets [ ]

Answer (score 4):

`solana-keygen recover 'prompt:?key=0/0' -o phantom_wallet.json`

Comment: thanks bro this was the solution i don't know why it was generating different keys using the bip39 and web3.Keypair.fromSeed but now i generate them using SOLANA CLI and it's working thank you very much bro.